# How to know when a clickonce application's installation process is finished?

Tags: .net, clickonce

In my current project, we are running clickonce applications from our main application.
We have some tasks to perform once the clickonce app is ready (i.e. installed and run).

I'd like to know if there is a way to know when the clickonce has finished the installation and the program is ready.

I cannot modify the clickonce programs.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There's no great way, especially if you can't modify the ClickOnce apps.

Can you just poll for the process existence?

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("ClickOnceApp");
```

Comment: That's what I feared...  Does the app name change when the download is finished ?  I tried looking in the task manager, but it's too quick (talk about first world problem... :-) )

Comment: Can you give more details about the specific tasks you need to perform after the app is installed?

Comment: The goal is to execute some automation tests once the app is ready.  This part works well, and we never experienced any problem right now, but we are foolproofing, as the installation time could be very long for whatever reason.